# Calculated Property wrt JPA. Does this work in my case?

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I have a scenario where I have 2 labels that need to be configured. The names of the labels are 'Out Date' and 'In Date'. I only have one field in the database called 'Date'. Whether it is 'Out' or 'In' is decided at the runtime by the value of an Enum 'Scenario'. However, I need to actually show the user Out Date&In Date so that he can select 1 or both of them. I heard that calculated field concept it JPA will assist in this. Is this true or is there some other way that I can achieve this. Below is some sample code.

Date

```
@Override
@Convert("DateTimeConverter")
@Column(name = "DATE")
public DateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Scenario

```
@Override
@Convert("EnumConverter")
@Column(name = "SCENARIO")
public Scenario getScenario() {
    return scenario;
}
```

Scenario is any enum with the values OUT(1),IN(2)

Comment: Hello, have you finally found a proper solution to your issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are no calculated properties in JPA.

You can use `@Transient` annotation to create properties that are not persisted but calculated based on other fields:

```
@Transient
public DateTime getInDate() {
    if (scenario == Scenario.IN) {
        return date;
    }
    return null;
}

@Transient
public DateTime getOutDate() {
    if (scenario == Scenario.OUT) {
        return date;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using Hibernate you can use proprietary annotation `@Formula`:

```
@Formula("case when SCENARIO = 2 then DATE else NULL end")
@Convert("DateTimeConverter")
private DateTime inDate;

@Formula("case when SCENARIO = 1 then DATE else NULL end")
@Convert("DateTimeConverter")
private DateTime outDate;
```

I prefer the first option because:

- it is easier to test with unit tests
- it is easier to use the entity in unit tests
- it does not require proprietary extensions
- generally there might be some problems with portability of SQL, although in this problem `case when` is SQL 92 compatible so it does not apply here

The only problem I can is is that in simplest approach is that we abandon encapsulation by exposing to clients internals of the entity (`scenario` and `date` properties). But you can always hide these properties with accessor `protected`, JPA will still handle that.

Comment: There are no calculated properties but  JPA callbacks help to calculate properties after entity loading.

Answer (score 1):

To compute properties within JPA entities, you can use JPA callbacks.

See this Hibernate [JPA Callbacks](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html/ch12.html#d5e1611) documentation. (Note: JPA callbacks are not specific to hibernate, it's part of latest JPA 2.1 [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)).
And also this OpenJpa [JPA Calbacks](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_pc_callbacks.html) one.

Following entity life-cycle categories have a *Pre* and *Post* event which can be intercepted by the entity manager to invoke methods:

- Persist -> [@PrePersist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/PrePersist.html), [@PostPersist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/PostPersist.html)
- Remove -> [@PreRemove](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/PreRemove.html), [@PostRemove](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/PostRemove.html)
- Update -> [@PreUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html), [@PostUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/PostUpdate.html)
- Load -> [@PostLoad](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html) (No *Pre* for this ...)

So let's say you want to compute a *complexLabel* label from two persisted entity fields *label1* and *label2* in an entity titled *MyEntity*:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    private String label1;

    private String label2;

    @Transient
    private String complexLabel;

    @PostLoad
    @PostUpdate // See EDIT
    // ...
    public void computeComplexLabel(){
        complexLabel = label1 + "::" + label2;
    }
}
```

As @Dawid wrote, you have to annotate *complexLabel* with *@Transient* in order to make them ignored by persistence. If you don't do this, persistence fails because there is no such column in *MyEntity* corresponding table.

With *@PostLoad* annotation, *computeComplexLabel()* method is called by entity manager just after the loading of any instance of *MyEntity* from persistence. 
Thus, *@PostLoad* annotated method is best suited to put your post loading entity properties enhancement code.

Bellow is an extract from JPA 2.1 specification about *PostLoad*:

> The *PostLoad* method for an entity is invoked after the entity has been
>   loaded into the current persistence context from the database or
>   after the refresh operation has been applied to it.  The *PostLoad*
>   method is invoked before a query result is returned or accessed or
>   before an association is traversed.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @Dawid, you could also use @PostUpdate in case you want to compute this transient field just after the entity update, and use other callbacks when needed.

Comment: This is another option. However, the problem with this approach is that property calculated in this way is not updated when you change entity. You also need to use `@PostUpdate` annotation. Frankly, using JPA lifecycle methods for field that could be easily calculated introduces unnecessary complexity and makes unit testing harder. Additionally, you need to be very careful. For entities in detached state lifecycle methods (especially `@PostUpdate`) will not work leaving you with stale data.

Comment: I agree with you @Dawid for the PostUpdate (as you often want to compute again this calculated property after entity update). However, using JPA callbacks optimize this computation as it is performed only after loading (@PostLoad) or update (@PostUpdate) but not each time you get the value, calling the getter as in your example. Then, I use to keep getters very simple so they don't calculate anything but just return the field value.  About tests, I use to cover this with integration or component tests using a real persistence unit with a real DB or an in-memory one.

Comment: I agree with you, @Rémi, in cases when computation is requires lots of resources. Then we can think about using JPA lifecycle methods. However, in most cases, especially one described in the question, IMHO performance gains do not justify introduced complexity (just 1 if statement if I got it right). Some team members might not know or have never used JPA lifecycle methods. Possibility to write simple unit tests instead of integration tests with complex setup is also something tempting.

Comment: Integration tests are really not too complex to setup for that, and they're good to check you haven't missed something in your entity definition and your queries. (And with a nice DSL to insert your fixtures it's even better). (You don't need Arquillian for that) But I agree that with your example, it's really not required. It depends on how complex is the computation... For this example with String concatenation (complexLabel), I find it complex enough to not be part of a getter. (It seems like we'll join a chat room soon ;) )